# GCC OpenMP target 'not a mappable type' error when using Armadillo

Tags: c++, gcc, gpu, openmp, armadillo

I am trying to rewrite a algorithm parallelized with OpenMP to try out the target accel. device capabilities of OMP. I stumbled over the following problem (I have prepared a minimal example):
When trying to access an Armadillo matrix object within the target region the following error is produced while compiling (with GCC 9.3.0, Cuda 10.1.243):

```
user@machine:~/tmp/gpu-test$ g++ -fopenmp -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector -foffload='-larmadillo' minimal.cxx -larmadillo
minimal.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
minimal.cxx:9:41: error: ‘mtotal’ does not have a mappable type in ‘map’ clause
    9 | parallel for map(tofrom: total) map(to: mtotal) reduction(+:total)
      |                                         ^~~~~~
minimal.cxx:11:28: error: ‘mtotal’ referenced in target region does not have a mappable type
   11 |         total += mtotal(0,0);
      |                            ^
```

The minimal example:

```
#include <armadillo>

int main() {

    double total = 0;
    arma::mat mtotal(1,1,arma::fill::randu);

#pragma omp target teams distribute \
parallel for map(tofrom: total) map(to: mtotal) reduction(+:total)
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        total += mtotal(0,0);
    }//for
}//main
```

I have tried to find out what 'not mappable type' means in this case but after searching I cannot make the connection to the arma::mat object. Also, I have already produced functioning code with my setup that runs on my GPU, so it shouldn't be a problem with the setup itself.

Comment: OpenMP restricts what can be mapped to the GPU device.  Basically, only things that you can copy with plain `memcpy` can be mapped.  I guess that the `arma:mat` type is not a POD (i.e., s truct), but rather a more complex C++ class type that contains a pointer type that cannot be copied automatically. The error you're seeing at least points into that direction.

Comment: Although I have not found direct confirmation of this, this explanation seems highly likely. If you want to post it as a normal answer, I can mark this as accepted

Comment: If you know the internal structure of the `arma::mat` type and you're using OpenMP 5.0, it's possible to define how any type should be mapped using a `declare mapper` construct.