# GCC OpenMP target ptxas error "Label expected for argument 0 of instruction 'call'" when using Eigen

Tags: c++, gcc, gpu, openmp, eigen3

I am trying to rewrite an algorithm parallelized with OpenMP to try out the target accel. device capabilities of OMP. I stumbled over the following problem (see example) when trying to use Eigen (3.4 rc1) within the OMP construct:

Minimal Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <cmath>

using Eigen::MatrixXd;

int main() {
    int n = 100000000;
    double total = 0;
    MatrixXd m(1,1);
    m(0,0) = 1;

   #pragma omp target teams distribute\
    parallel for map(tofrom: total) map(to: n, m) reduction(+:total)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        total +=m(0,0)* exp(sin(M_PI * (double) i/12345.6789));
    }
        std::cout << "total is " << total << '\n';
}
```

Compiling with (both gcc 9.3 and 10.2 tested, nvptx-none target, CUDA 10.1.243)

```
g++ -I ./eigen-3.4-rc1 -fopenmp -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector -foffload=nvptx-none='--verbose -lm' eigen-total-omp.cxx -lm
```

Obvious Error (for full verbose output, see below)

```
ptxas /tmp/ccnYX8aR.o, line 262; error   : Label expected for argument 0 of instruction 'call'
ptxas /tmp/ccnYX8aR.o, line 262; fatal   : Call target not recognized
```

I haven't found explicit confirmation that Eigen works with the OMP target directive, however, it apparently should work [with "normal" CUDA](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCUDA.html).
The error is not very helpful (or at least I cannot gleam insight from it), but moving the init. of the matrix object into the for loop produces one additional error:

```
ptxas /tmp/ccl3LNcx.o, line 277; error   : Label expected for argument 0 of instruction 'call'
ptxas /tmp/ccl3LNcx.o, line 277; error   : Function '_ZN5Eigen6MatrixIdLin1ELin1ELi0ELin1ELin1EEC1IiiEERKT_RKT0_' not declared in this scope
ptxas /tmp/ccl3LNcx.o, line 277; fatal   : Call target not recognized
```

So my guess is that somehow the library is not seen within the loop by the compilers for the target device? Neither adding the Eigen path to `-foffload` nor (one of the only things I stumbled across) adding the `-fno-exceptions` flag changed anything.

Thank you for your time!

---

Full (verbose) error output

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc-9
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/accel/nvptx-none/lto-wrapper
Target: nvptx-none
Configured with: ../src/configure --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib --with-gcc-major-version-only --disable-bootstrap --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-newlib-io-long-long --target nvptx-none --enable-as-accelerator-for=x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --without-isl --program-prefix=nvptx-none- --program-suffix=-9
Thread model: single
gcc version 9.3.0 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-m64' '-mgomp' '-fno-openacc' '-fPIC' '-foffload-abi=lp64' '-fopenmp' '-fcf-protection=none' '-v' '-v' '-o' '/tmp/ccDYQmTY.mkoffload'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/accel/nvptx-none/lto1 -quiet -dumpbase ccYsZMdw.o -m64 -mgomp -auxbase ccYsZMdw -version -fno-openacc -fPIC -foffload-abi=lp64 -fopenmp -fcf-protection=none @/tmp/ccllzqV5 -o /tmp/ccpHq0W6.s
GNU GIMPLE (GCC) version 9.3.0 (nvptx-none)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.3.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version none
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
GNU GIMPLE (GCC) version 9.3.0 (nvptx-none)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.3.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version none
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-m64' '-mgomp' '-fno-openacc' '-fPIC' '-foffload-abi=lp64' '-fopenmp' '-fcf-protection=none' '-v' '-v' '-o' '/tmp/ccDYQmTY.mkoffload'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/accel/nvptx-none/as -o /tmp/ccRXK6K4.o /tmp/ccpHq0W6.s
ptxas /tmp/ccRXK6K4.o, line 264; error   : Label expected for argument 0 of instruction 'call'
ptxas /tmp/ccRXK6K4.o, line 264; fatal   : Call target not recognized
ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
nvptx-as: ptxas returned 255 exit status
mkoffload: fatal error: x86_64-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc-9 returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9//accel/nvptx-none/mkoffload returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

Update 1: Accessing the data from a pointer throws an `libgomp: cuCtxSynchronize error: an illegal memory access was encountered` error

```
int main() {
    int n = 10;
    double total = 0;
    MatrixXd m(1,1);
    m(0,0) = 1;

    double* array = m.data();
    std::cout << "array: " << array[0] <<std::endl; //this works

   #pragma omp target teams distribute\
    parallel for map(tofrom: total) map(to: n, array) reduction(+:total)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        total +=array[0]; //this trows an error
    }
        std::cout << "total is " << total << '\n';
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `map` of OpenMP only works for low-level arrays (C arrays and pointers to memory area), not for high-level C++ objects. Thus, I think you need to work with pointers, not Eigen matrices. Note that you could probably unwrap the Eigen matrix to a row pointer for the OpenMP device mapping and wrap the pointer again in the loop using Eigen as Eigen provide mapped arrays. All of this seems cumbersome, but OpenMP is not aware that Eigen types are matrices. Actually, this this the same problem than in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67267662...

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the information. If I understand you correctly I should be able to hand off a pointer to the data through the map directive and then remake the Eigen matrix within the loop from the pointer? Because if that is what you meant, if I do any call to an Eigen object/function (as in just initializing a new matrix for example) I get the same error as described above with the "not declared in this scope" message.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean, but be careful: I did not mean to create a full new matrix object but just a view. I guess views should works. Keep in mind that the inner part of the loop is executed on the GPU and thus have some stronger limitation than usual C++. Alternatively, the problem may be due to some limitation of GCC. Can you try with GCC-10?

Comment: I tried both gcc 9.3 and 10.2. Both Matrix initialization and building a Map object from the data pointer of the previous matrix (or did you mean another View technique) throw the above mentioned `Function 'blabla' not declared in this scope` error. Furthermore, but that problably has something to do with my inexperience with pointer handling in the map clause, I get an `libgomp: cuCtxSynchronize error: an illegal memory access was encountered` when trying to access the data after handing of the pointer to the gpu (but it works before the omp directive). Maybe I did it wrong (see edit)?